# initWithReceiverApplicationID is deprecated Use initWithDiscoveryCriteria warning Chromecast

Tags: ios, chromecast

```
GCKCastOptions* options =
            [[GCKCastOptions alloc] initWithReceiverApplicationID:kGoogleChromeCastApplicationID];
```

Initialization line of Google Chromecast start to gives me this warning:

```
'initWithReceiverApplicationID:' is deprecated: Use initWithDiscoveryCriteria:
```

Did anyone use the new way of initiating?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I pass the warning:

```
GCKDiscoveryCriteria *criteria = [[GCKDiscoveryCriteria alloc] initWithApplicationID:kGoogleChromeCastApplicationID];
GCKCastOptions* options = [[GCKCastOptions alloc] initWithDiscoveryCriteria:criteria];
```

Hope this helps!

Best